# opening react app should redirect to default signin page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation-drawer, sidebar

I have a react application where in I have implemented Dashboard and signin pages. I want the homepage to be signin. Sign In page redirects to dashboard. But I'm unable to get the homepage to redirect to signin. This is what I've tried so far :-

App.js File :-

```
const LoginContainer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/signin" />} /> 
      <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
    </div>
  );
}

const DefaultContainer = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Drawer />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={LoginContainer} />
          <Route component={DefaultContainer} />

        </Switch>
      </Router>       
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is this not being redirected to signin Page as default.

Comment: where is your logic to redirect page,

Comment: LoginContainer has the logic @AkhilAravind

Answer (score -2):

in the App.js file

use this. 
Redirect from App.js, not from login container

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/signin"/>} /> 
          <Route component={DefaultContainer} />

        </Switch>
      </Router>       
    </div>
  );
}


const LoginContainer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
    </div>
  );
}
```